# Centering Div's with Images

Tags: html, css

I have 4 Images, and for some reasons my brain stopped working and i cant figure out why i cant center those.

That's the Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/theminijohn/bcMX5/

If i try to just `<center>` them i'm getting a `Deprecated Html Tag Error` in my Editor.

I tried a lot of things, till rewriting the Css and Html Code, but i'm brain stuck here.

Could some Gentleman help brake my blockade ? :)

Comment: if all margin's are 0 then just do margin:50%; http://jsfiddle.net/bcMX5/3/

Comment: I have Margins, on a try now, margin:50% is not working. You are free  to try that on my Fiddle tho.

Comment: click on the link above, works for me. Are you trying to center each image vertically too?

Comment: Are you trying to horizontally center the div's in a single row or one div per line?

Comment: Checked the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

Add a wrapper block element around your `div`'s and then apply the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Center 4 Blocks */
 .hd_b {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
._hd {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
._hd:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
._hd img {
    opacity: .85;
}
._hd a:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QTxy9/

The parent `.wrap` block has `text-align: center`, and this will center the child `._hd` div's that have `display: inline-block`.

You need to reset the right margin on the last child div using `._hd:last-child`.

This works pretty well if you are willing to use the inline-block display type.

Note that any white space between inline-block elements translate into a 1ex wide space, which may not be obvious when you set the margin between blocks.

Comment: Sweet, That's exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 1):

All of those divs need to be in one container div that has a fixed width.  Then you can apply `margin: 0 auto` to the container.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcMX5/9/

Comment: Worked, thank you. But isn't it a bit wrong to set a fix width? Cause with a Responsive Layout it isn't working.

Comment: You could use `@media (max-width: 480px) { //CSS relative to width }`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:-

Give a "main" DIV outside all img DIV "`<div id="main">`"

and give "`margin: 0 auto;`" along with some width to it.

Please refer the Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/6U2YJ/**

Hope this should solve your issue!

Comment: Thanks :) I Checked Dockerys answer (the same as yours) he just was quicker :/. Thanks Anyways.

Answer (score 0):

would this be, want you want?
._hd {
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: I tried that, but with width:100% it just takes all the divs in to a vertical column. :/

Comment: So how exactly do you want to "center" your images?

Comment: Checked the Correct Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `margin` and `float` ;) http://jsfiddle.net/bcMX5/8/

```
._hd {
    //margin-right: 20px;
    display: block;
    //float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but with that, it centers them in to one Column.. Checked the Answer that worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to center the elements? If it's in a column the above answer would work. Its in a grid then wrap them in a fixed width container.

```
._hd_container{
    width:440px;
    margin:0 auto;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RzfMP/